# How to access a local variable's value in this situation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, counter

I'm trying to read the number of times an event has been logged and increment/decrement a variable accordingly. **Since I can't use this.setState inside the getPastEvent (because it generates an Unhandled Runtime Error which is TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined)**, I'm opting for this method where I perform my counting on a local variable then save it to the state variable.

The issue here is when I use `this.setState({totalBidders: biddersnumber});` at the end of the function, I receive the value zero where in my case it should be two! How can I get the value of the counter `biddersnumber` in this situation?

```js
componentDidMount = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  const plasticBaleSC = plasticBaleContract(this.props.address);

  var biddersnumber = 0;
  var highestbid = 0;

  plasticBaleSC.getPastEvents('allEvents', { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' }, function (error, events) {
    console.log(events);
    events.forEach(myfunction);

    function myfunction(item, index) {
      if (item.event === 'bidderRegistered') {
        console.log(item);
        biddersnumber++;
        //value is two here
        console.log(biddersnumber);
      } else if (item.event === 'bidPlaced') {
      } else if (item.event === 'bidderRegistered') {
      } else if (item.event === 'bidderExited') {
        console.log(item);
        biddersnumber--;
      } else if (item.event === 'auctionStarted') {
      }
    }
  });

  //Value is zero here
  this.setState({ totalBidders: biddersnumber });
}
```

Comment: use an arrow function instead ... change `function (error, events){` to `(error, events) => {` and change `function myfunction(item,index){` to be `const myfunction = (item, index) =>` and move it before the `forEach`. Alternatively, `const self = this;` on top and `self.setState(...)` whenever you like.

Comment: why don't you update the state in `getPastEvents`?

Comment: I can't use it inside getPastEvents because it generates the error:  Unhandled Runtime Error which is TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the call to `setState` inside your callback:

```
     // ....
    var highestbid =0;
    const that = this

    // ....

     // Value is two here
     that.setState({totalBidders: biddersnumber});
   });

   //Value is zero here 

};
```

You'll need to deal with `this`, so assign it to `that` like it's 2010.

Comment: This generates the following error: Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Using comments on this question, I did the following updates to resolve the issue. Thank you Andrea!

```
componentDidMount = async () => {

        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        const plasticBaleSC = plasticBaleContract(this.props.address); 

        var biddersnumber = 0; 
        var highestbid =0;

        plasticBaleSC.getPastEvents("allEvents",{fromBlock: 0, toBlock:'latest'},(error, events)=>{
            console.log(events);

            const myfunction = (item,index) => {

                if(item.event==='bidderRegistered'){
                    console.log(item);
                    biddersnumber++; 
                    console.log(biddersnumber);
                    

                }else if(item.event==='bidPlaced'){


                }else if(item.event==='bidderRegistered'){

                }else if (item.event==='bidderExited'){
                    console.log(item);
                    biddersnumber--;

                }else if(item.event==='auctionStarted'){
                    //console.log(item);
                    //this.setState({highestBid: item.returnValues['startingAmount']});

                }


            };

            events.forEach(myfunction);

            this.setState({totalBidders: biddersnumber});

    });

   
    };
```